# How to print Freemarker list options in two separate columns while looping

Tags: freemarker

I would like in Freemaker that my value is listed in 2 columns.

My code so far :

```
<#list orderItem.options as option>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size: 16px;">
            <div class="row">
                <#if option.fileUrls??>
                    <span>
                        <span>${option.name}:
                        </span>
                        <@fileLinks option.fileUrls = "option.fileUrls"/>
                    </span>

                <#else>
                    <#if option.value != 'Geen'>
                        <div class="column">${option.name}: ${option.value}</div>
                        ${option.name}: ${option.value}
                        -                                                                                  -
                    </#if>
                </#if>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</#list>
```

So I want :

I have a webshop where people can buy food.

Food can have multiple options : Size, Salt, Saus

I want that my products will be printed in my mail this way :

Product name :         Product name:

Size: small                 Size: Big
Salt : Yes                    Salt: no 
Saus: Mayonaise       Saus: Cocktail

Answer (score 1):

You really should be limiting the scope of your question's example. I am not sure what the extra markup should do, or where it should be placed. But is it something like this you are looking for?

```
<table>
<#list orderItem.options as option>
  <#if option.fileUrls??>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span>${option.name}</span>
        <span><@fileLinks option.fileUrls/></span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <#if option.value != 'Geen'>
          <span>${option.value}</span>
        </#if>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </#if>
</#list>
</table>
```

I am sorry if this is not exactly what you are looking for, but your example is confusing. At least you might take my example response and go from there.

Comment: I am sorry. My english is not that well. 

So Maybe I try an other way to explain myself.


I have a webshop where people can buy food. 

Food can have multiple options : Size, Salt, Saus 

I want that my products will be printed in my mail this way : 

Product name :         Product name: 

Size: small                 Size: Big
Salt : Yes                    Salt: no 
Saus: Mayonaise       Saus: Cocktail

Answer (score 0):

I have couple questions if you don't mind:

- Is Product name also part of the options stored in `orderItem.options` ?
- Is having file link exclusive to a certain option ?
- Please edit your question and post the Java model (class) `OrderItem`

I got what you want, need to know your design approach to provide the best solution that suites your design.